# Form's abandonment rate is always 100% in sitecore forms extension

Tags: sitecore-forms

We are using `Sitecore 9.0.2` and `Sitecore Forms Extensions` for the `Sitecore 9.0-1.8.2 module`.

In our forms for Submit we are using multiple actions like Save data, Identify contect, Send Email and Show form page.

[image]

Identify contact action
[image]

In the form dashboard when we look at the form's performance, the abandonment rate is always 100%.

[image]

Abandonment rate says `*percentage not submitting the form*`.On testing the forms are always submitted an email is triggered. 
Also, the percentage goes down for a while and when we check after an hour or so its back to 100%. 
Any idea of how this works?

Comment: Since you are using 'Identify contect' action, can you make sure Xconnect is working fine? also could you please try by removing this action for testing purpose?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat , we dint had 'Identify Contact' option before, inorder to fix this we added. I removed this option and tested its still showing the abandonment rate as 100%

Comment: What are all the actions you have on form submit?

Comment: @YogeshSharma Save data, 3 Send Email and Show Form Page(for thank you message)

Comment: any idea guys ??

Comment: I do see the same behavior in our forms as well. @user3267206 Did you find out the root cause/solution?

Comment: I have the same issue and never managed to resolve it. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the Sitecore Forms Extensions module, you should set the `Navigation step` to `Submit` and then add the `Show Form Page` Submit action, which is a custom action of the SFE module.

You can the select the "Page" element to show on submit, instead of having to redirect the user to a separate thank you page.

[image: Add submit action]

[image: Select page element top show]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check whether the navigation step in the form is set to submit. Because Sitecore only registers the form as submitted when there is a submit button with Navigation step set to “Submit”, which is configured in Sitecore Forms dll.

If you have the navigation step as next and thank you message in the next page, this will perform the next action regardless of having submit action. For this, you can place the ‘Thank you page’ at the separate Sitecore item and use the ‘Redirect to Page’ submit action to navigate to it. You can find out more [here](https://joaoneto.blog/when-multi-page-forms-submission-are-accounted-as-abandoned)